# Deep learning theano

Tags: machine-learning

I use Theano for developing a convolutional neural network using keras library.
when i tried to run my code , i reported the following error:

AssertionError: AbstractConv2d Theano optimization failed: there is no implementation available supporting the requested options. Did you exclude both "conv_dnn" and "conv_gemm" from the optimizer? If on GPU, is cuDNN available and does the GPU support it? If on CPU, do you have a BLAS library installed Theano can link against?

Please I need specific steps to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `optimizer = None` to your .theanorc file
A sample .theanorc file might look like:

```
[global]
device = gpu
optimizer = None
[cuda]
root = /usr/local/cuda-VERSION
```

Comment: where  can i find this file?

Comment: If you use Linux, it is in your /home directory. If it is not there, make a file called .theanorc in /home. The .theanorc is the config file that tells theano what to do when you use it. You can configure your default device (CPU vs GPU), your cuda root directory, and your optimizer.

Comment: No, i use windows 7 and intel graphics .

Comment: An  OpenBLAS library , can help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: There is a step by step tutorial for installing Theano on windows, [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html)

Comment: Many Thanks  for your effort. I changed optimizer to  None and my code run successfully